# react-dates Cannot read property 'clone' of null at new DayPicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, react-dates

I have below code

```js
const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState('startDate');
const onFocusChange = fInput => {
  setFocusedInput(!fInput ? 'startDate' : fInput);
};

<DayPickerRangeController
  key={dateRange.startDate}
  startDate={dateRange.startDate}
  endDate={dateRange.endDate}
  onDatesChange={onDatesChange}
  onFocusChange={onFocusChange}
  focusedInput={focusedInput}
  numberOfMonths={2}
  isOutsideRange={day => moment().diff(day) < 0}
  initialVisibleMonth={() => dateRange.startDate}
/>
```

**initialVisibleMonth** causing the issue

> Cannot read property 'clone' of null at new DayPicker

I tried googling alot but didn't find any solution. What I am trying move the calendar to first month.. like I am on dec 2020 and someone select this year, it should show the the calendar to jan 2020, This year selection is fine, I am seeing the whole year is selected in calendar just the month is not shifting to jan so that it can be visible

Any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've passed a function not a value to `initialVisibleMonth` prop. `dateRange.startDate` seems like not a function, but you used it like a function.

Change

```
initialVisibleMonth={() => dateRange.startDate}
```

to

```
initialVisibleMonth={dateRange.startDate}
```